# Purpose of using it is okay..is it being polite?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, types-of-sentences

What's the difference between

> You can have a drink now.

and

> It is okay to have a drink now.

Answer (score 3):

Using

> **It is okay**

is not necessarily being polite.   In your examples, both have the same effect, the speaker is the person with authority to grant permission.

> **You can have a drink now.**
>   **It is okay to have a drink now.**

both have the same meaning, the second is usually used when there is an explicit condition given to *not* drink, but is now possible.

You will find that in situations where you would use

> **It's okay to have a drink now.**

you might also use

> **Don't worry, it's okay.**
>   **Don't worry** *(about drinking now)*, **it's okay.**